# Making userscript that inserts a div into the Facebook newsfeed

Tags: javascript, facebook, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm making a Tampermonkey userscript that inserts a button div into the Facebook newsfeed. I've been able to do this on other websites (I tried it on Youtube, for instance), but for some reason, I'm having trouble with Facebook. The button isn't not showing up on Facebook... any ideas? I'm pretty new to all this. Many thanks.

```
/ Author: klsdkhldi
// Written: 2019-22-19
// Last modified: 2019-22-19
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Jerry
// @namespace    http://www.fivesided.com/facebook_bull
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @include      https://*.facebook.com/*
// @exclude      https://*.facebook.com/login.php
// @version      1.0
// @downloadURL  https://gist.github.com/danguyf/16557d077dac43efbb2cf365a7db3945/raw/facebook_bull.user.js
// ==/UserScript==

function polymerInject(){

    /* Create button */
    var buttonDiv = document.createElement("div");
    buttonDiv.style.width = "100%";
    buttonDiv.id = "parentButton";

    var addButton = document.createElement("button");
    addButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download MP3"));

    if(typeof(document.getElementById("iframeDownloadButton")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("iframeDownloadButton") !== null){

        document.getElementById("iframeDownloadButton").remove();

    }

    addButton.style.width = "100%";
    addButton.style.backgroundColor = "#181717";
    addButton.style.color = "white";
    addButton.style.textAlign = "center";
    addButton.style.padding = "10px 0";
    addButton.style.marginTop = "5px";
    addButton.style.fontSize = "14px";
    addButton.style.border = "0";
    addButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
    addButton.style.borderRadius = "2px";
    addButton.style.fontFamily = "Roboto, Arial, sans-serif";

    addButton.onclick = function () {

        this.remove();
    };

    buttonDiv.appendChild(addButton);

    /* Find and add to target */
    var targetElement = document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label$='Story options']");

    for(var i = 0; i < targetElement.length; i++){

    }

    /* Fix hidden description bug */
    var descriptionBox = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer");
    if(descriptionBox[0].className.indexOf("loading") > -1){

        descriptionBox[0].classList.remove("loading");

    }

}
if(document.getElementById("polymer-app") || document.getElementById("masthead") || window.Polymer){

    setInterval(function(){

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("watch?v=") < 0){

            return false;

        }

        if(document.getElementById("count") && document.getElementById("parentButton") === null){

            polymerInject();


        }

    }, 100);

}

else{

    standardInject();

}

waitForKeyElements("[aria-label='Story options']", polymerInject);
```

Comment: You have to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want to get help here. In your case MCVE must contain a [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#manifest) at least.

Comment: Hi! I'm using tampermonkey (https://www.tampermonkey.net/), which has that internally — basically, if you have the tampermonkey extension, you can just plug what I have here into it, and you'll have exactly what I have.

Comment: Then your question's irrelevant to "chrome extensions", as you're actually writing a userscript, not chrome extension.

Comment: Ok. I don't know the vocab so well — I'm trying to make a chrome extension, and I'm starting with a working userscript that I can later turn into a full extension since all the similar code I can find is userscripts.

Comment: AFAIU you're only going to make an extension from userscript in the future, but at the moment you can't even make the userscript work and want someone to make it for you. So your post is off-topic twice: as you're asking to debug your userscript for you and then help converting it to a chrome extension. Note that asking multiple distinct questions in one post is illegal here.

Comment: What? I'm not asking for anyone to write my userscript for me or to turn it into a Chrome extension. I wrote the userscript myself, and I can't figure out why it's not working — you're the one who started talking about Chrome extensions.

Comment: You'll find this is extremely difficult; Facebook regularly changes the HTML and injects nonsense into it to prevent third-party extensions from manipulating or parsing the feed at all. Right-click on the "Sponsored" grey text of an ad for example - each letter gets wrapped in a class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually have figured out how to find each facebook post and make a red border around it, so I'm okay on that bit.

Comment: i think part of the problem may be that facebook uses the React js library for all its front end code, and  it can be tricky to insert elements into react js code, as react seems to refresh its frontend code to rid itself of any impure (non react js code / html elements)